# Codeigniter, error when send multiple email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm doing a newsletter method but when I send multiple mail, it fail from the second mail to the ultimate. I don't know where's the problem.

Here my code:

```
$this->load->library('email');

            $this->email->from('newsletter@xxxxxx.yy', 'xxxxxx');
            $data = array();
            $data["content"] = $contenuto;

            foreach($result->result() as $row){
                $this->email->clear(TRUE);
                $data["footer_link"] = "<p><a href=\"http://localhost/xxxxx/public/landing/unsub/". $row->email ."\">Clicca qui</a> per disinscriverti dalla newsletter</p>"; //unsubscribe newsletter

                $this->email->to($row->email);
                $body = $this->load->view("templates/entire_page.php", $data, TRUE);

            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($body);
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

            if($this->email->send()){
                echo $row->email.': email inviata con successo!<br>'; //email sent
            }else{
                echo $row->email.": Impossibile inviare l'email: Errore.<br>"; //email not sent
            }

            }
```

example of my errors:

```
dunkey@munkey.com: email inviata con successo! (sented)
dunkey@chicken.com: Impossibile inviare l'email: Errore. (not sented)
dunkey@csgo.com: Impossibile inviare l'email: Errore. (not sented)
```

I'm very sorry for the italian in this post but I commented it with the relative translation.
I hope I was clear, Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: [Try using the `print_debugger()` to see what the returned error message is.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::print_debugger)

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I moved the "from" after the "clear".

Here the code:

```
        $data = array();
        $data["content"] = $contenuto;

        foreach($result->result() as $row){
        $this->email->clear(TRUE);
        $this->email->from('newsletter@xxxxxx.yy', 'xxxxxx');
        // ...other code...
```